# Mongoose Population ObjectId ref's are disappearing?

Tags: node.js, mongoose, population

I've simplified the code below:

```
var buySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    userid:String,
    timestamp:Number,
    price:Number
});
var cardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    cardid: String,
    buy:[{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'buy'}],
});

var Card = mongoose.model('cards',cardSchema,'cards');
var Buy = mongoose.model('buy',buySchema,'buy');

Card.findOne({'cardid':cardid}, function(err, card) {

    var newBuy = new Buy({'userid':userid, timestamp:null,price:null});

    newBuy.save(function(err){
      card.buy.addToSet(newBuy._id);
    });

    card.save(function(err,card){
      console.log(card.buy); // card.buy[] has an ObjectId ref
    });

});

Card.findOne({'cardid':cardid}, function(err, card) {
   console.log(card.buy); // !!!!! card.buy[] does not have ObjectId ref !!!!!
});
```

buy[] does not ever appear to have an ObjectId ref saved in mongodb either

How am I supposed to populate a card later on if there are no ObjectId refs? Where did they go? What am I not getting about population?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `newBuy.save` call is asynchronous, so your `card.save` call is occurring before your `card.buy.addToSet` call.

So reorder that part of your code as either:

```
newBuy.save(function(err){
  card.buy.addToSet(newBuy._id);
  card.save(function(err,card){
    console.log(card.buy);
  });
});
```

OR

```
newBuy.save(function(err){
});

card.buy.addToSet(newBuy._id);
card.save(function(err,card){
  console.log(card.buy);
});
```

Comment: Thanks! Just figured this one out at the same time :)

Answer (score 1):

You have to add quotes for ref:'buy' and add corectly schema. Look mongoosejs [docs](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html).

```
var cardSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
    cardid: String,
    buy:[{type:mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId, ref:'buy'}],
});

var Card = mongoose.model('cards',cardSchema);
var Buy = mongoose.model('buy',buySchema);
```

Comment: Thank you for pointing this out. You are correct, however the issue still persists and the behavior is exactly the same.  I have updated my code to reflect the changes suggested.

Answer (score 0):

So when saving the child, you have to save the parent inside the callback of the child's save like so:

```
newBuy.save(function(err){
  card.buy.addToSet(newBuy._id);
  card.save(function(err,card){
    console.log(card.buy); // card.buy[] has an ObjectId ref & is actually saved to db
  });
});
```